# remote sudo from local script with local redirection

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect, sudo

Okay I'm sure this has been asked before but the life of me I can't find an answer (it's not possible / how to do it).

I have a shell script script.sh which runs a command on a remote server using:

```
    ssh -t [SERVER] "[COMMAND TO BE EXECUTED REMOTELY]"
```

This works fine including if the command contains sudo.

However, sometimes I redirect the output of this script.sh and of course if the remote command contains sudo the sudo password prompt is redirected also.

Is there a way to:

```
    ./script.sh > script.out
```

and still get the remote sudo password prompt on the terminal?

Passing the sudo password on the cli for script.sh is not an option.

Many thanks,

Alasdair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tee to duplicate the standard input:

```
./script.sh | tee script.out
```

After that you can filter what is output with an awk command

```
./script.sh | tee script.out | awk '/^Password/ {print;}'
```

Comment: Yeah I was aware of tee, the trouble is there is alot of output hence the redirection and only wanting the sudo prompt to get all the way back to the terminal, however this may be the only solution. [Edit] would it be possible to just redirect the sudo prompt to stderr and leave the rest as stdout in ssh -t [SERVER] "sudo [REMOTE COMMAND]"

Comment: I am afraid that is going to be a bit difficult. Forwarding the output to stderr is as simple as doing >&2 but I don't think that is what you are looking for. But see my edit maybe it can help you.